# NHibernate never recognizes a joint request

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Good time of day! To create a query, use Create query method:

```cs
string query = $@"INSERT INTO [{table_name}] ([p1], [p2]) VALUES (:p1_val, :p2_val)";

Session.CreateQuery(query)
    .SetParameter("p1_val", p1_val)
    .SetParameter("p2_val", p2_val)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

When executing, the following error is returned:

```
A recognition error occurred. near line 1, column 12
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString)
<...>
```

Executable line of code (from the exception description):

```
INSERTINTO[<table_name>]([p1],[p2])VALUES(:p1_val,:p2_val)
```

Framework config:

```xml
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.connection_string"><connection_string></property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>
      <property name="adonet.batch_size">500</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

It seems that for some reason spaces are being removed in the request. However, until the last moment, this code worked correctly. What could be the reason for this? I'm just confused.

Comment: Any reason not to use objects? Also escaping is done through `config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Hbm2ddlKeyWords, NHibernate.Cfg.Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote.ToString())` so you dont have to do it in hql

Comment: @Firo, as far as I understand, you pointed to the config, but everything is fine with it.

Comment: I meant that you should not escape in a hqlquery at all. I suspect it messes up there somehow because column 12 is the `[` right?

Comment: @Firo, okay, the shielding is removed. Now the query string is going like this: ```query = $@"INSERT INTO {table_name} (p1, p2) VALUES (:p1_val, :p2_val)";```
But now the error is as follows:
```FROM expected (non-filter queries must contain a FROM clause)```
After all, this query is not HQL, but ordinary SQL. Now I don't understand anything at all)

Comment: if it is plain sql the use `session.Createsqlquery` with the escaping then

Comment: @Firo, yes, ```CreateSQLQuery``` method really works. Thanks! But I would like to get an explanation of why ```CreateQuery``` method stopped working?)

Comment: I guess this code is in some generic class and was not used or used where table name was the same as entity name. Or an update to NHibernate changed some behavior

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Firo's comment. As a result, the solution is to replace the `createQuery` method with `CreateSQLQuery`.